# QTP, How to click on the link within the webelement

Tags: hyperlink, qtp

I am new to QTP, and working on creating script for 'http://shopping.indiatimes.com/' site, in which I am trying to click on the link present within the web elements.

I have used the following link but it doesn't work correctly all the time,

```
B().P().link("name:=Clothes, Footwear & Jewellery","index:=0","html tag:=A").Click.
```

I want to know if I can access the same link using the web element (within which the link is present), which will run perfectly at all times.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: If you post the html of a sample page, you´ll get quite specific feedback, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the link after the webelement like this 
Browser().page().webelement().link().click

if there is no webelement to be added before the link find any table or frame ....